# Homomorphic Encryption CKKS scheme: How library SEAL represents in memory a Ciphertext

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm trying to understand how its represented a ciphertext of CKKS in memory, or the data structure.

Here is what I understand, correct me if I'm wrong. I also add some questions.

1. To start with, given a polynomial degree N and and a coefficient modulus, say {60, 40, 40, 60}. This means that the encoding in the CRT representation there will be 4 polynomials with two of them with coefficients of 60bits and two of them with coefficients of 40bits?
2. The same but in the ciphertext will be 2 polynomials that in CRT will be two of this 4 polynomials that i say in 1?
3. The Ciphertext is an array of Polynomials represented in a CRT form and also the parameter id. Correct? If so, this param_id is in the LSB or MSB?
4. What is the structure of a Polynomials in CRT form, is a array of arrays? In which each element correspond to one of the primes of the CRT? and inside this array has size equal to the polynomial degree and  each element is the correspond coefficient in order?
5. There is something else that in missing?

Comment: What is CKKS? Make your question more understandable.

Comment: Its one of the most popular schemes of HE. Because i add the HE flags I thought that will be clear. There I make it more understandable. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @mmazz - The point of it was to edit your question and make it more friendly to everyone.